# Bash Shell Script errors: ambiguous redirect and unary operator expected

Tags: bash, shell, operator-keyword, ambiguous

I'm totally new to writing code with `shell script`.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Output to $2 "
# set counter
count=1
# zap output file
> $2
# Loop
while [ $count -le $1 ]
do
    # generate some random text
    randomnumber=`od -A n -t d -N 1 /dev/urandom`
    randomtext=`cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd "[:alnum:]" | head -c $randomnumber`
    # generate a random number
    randomnumber=`od -A n -t d -N 1 /dev/urandom`
    # output to file
    echo "$count,$randomtext,$randomnumber" | sed -e "s: *::g" >> $2
    # increment counter
    count=$(($count + 1))
    if [ $(($count % 500)) -eq 0 ]
    then
echo -n "." fi
done
echo " Output complete"
```

And this is my error:

```
Line 2: ambiguous redirect and Line 14: unary operator expected.
```

Can anybody help me to understand why I having that error?

Comment: The line numbers don't align with the code. Please correct.

Comment: Looks like you need to validate user input. Have 2 arguments been provided?

Comment: Carefully read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Comment: `if [ $(($count % 500)) -eq 0 ]` can be simplified to `if (( $count % 500 == 0 ))` -- see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs

Answer (score 1):

As @GlennJackman points out, the lines are not matching the code, hence I am guessing the following:

- The ambiguous redirection is on line 6: To truncate a file, you
  should use `truncate -s0 $2`
- For the unary operator error, I bet on line 21: either put a linefeed
  or a semicolon `;` before `fi`

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Output to $2 "
# set counter
count=1
# zap output file
truncate -s0 $2
# Loop
while [ $count -le $1 ]
do
    # generate some random text
    randomnumber=`od -A n -t d -N 1 /dev/urandom`
    randomtext=`cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd "[:alnum:]" | head -c $randomnumber`
    # generate a random number
    randomnumber=`od -A n -t d -N 1 /dev/urandom`
    # output to file
    echo "$count,$randomtext,$randomnumber" | sed -e "s: *::g" >> $2
    # increment counter
    count=$(($count + 1))
    if [ $(($count % 500)) -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo -n "."
    fi
done
echo " Output complete"
```